# Why is my recursive function in python 3.6 returning two results?

Tags: python-3.6

I wrote this program in python to find the factorial of given input n:

`def factorial(n):
  count = n
  if n == 1:
    return n
  else:
    while count != 0:
      return n * n-1
      n -= 1
      count -= 1`

When I run it multiple times, it comes up with multiple answers for the same input. For example, I will run it at n = 5 and it returns 120 sometimes and 24 other times. This holds true for all of the numbers that I have tried. Why is this so?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to show your full code. There's nothing here that would cause it to return different values for same input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in logic. First of all, you are multiplying n by itself, and deduce 1 from it (missing brackets). Second, you should call factorial function recursively, in which case you don't need extra variable (`count`) and don't need `while` loop:

```
def factorial(n):
 if n <= 1:
   return 1
 else:
   return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong overall. When you pass `5` every single time the result will be `24` the reason is `return n * n-1` part. In the loop it should be `n*=n-1` instead of `return n * n-1` Also your loop must be `while n>1` and remove `count` at all. Good luck at school :)

Answer (score 0):

def fact(n):
   if n<=1:
      return 1
  else:
 return n * fact(n-1)